# What's the issue if the render doesn't return anything?

Tags: reactjs, render, scrollmagic

here is my code, and I created a component called showcase and called it from another component, but nothing appears in the window, Can somebody assist me?

> https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-fast-mpc1fc?file=/Usescase.jsx

Comment: Your App's code starts in src/App.js never in that file have you written anything else than is displayed on the screen.

Comment: Maybe if you can share your code. You might have forgot to save the file in codesandbox.